# Count bar number in two condition then count the result

Tags: pine-script

I want to start count the green bar number with a condition "close > close[1]"and store the number until I have 10 green bars, then compare those 10 bars close price, count 1 if bar 2 close higher than bar 1 until 8 times,

```
(200, 300, 500, 400, 600, 500, 800, 900, 1000, 1100)
       1    2         3         4    5    6      7
```

(say those are the close price of 10 green bars, then it's 7 times),
when counting the number, if one of those 10 bars close lower than previous one,
don't stop the counting until meet 8 times condition or over "Number of bars lookback" number, then rest the count, and counting again.

here is my code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Count", "C")
var int     barsBack        = input.int(30, 'Number of bars lookback', 0)

var int[]   greenBars       = array.new_int(barsBack, 0)
var int[]   redBars         = array.new_int(barsBack, 0)
var int     greenBarCount   = 0
var int     redBarCount     = 0

direction = ta.change(close)
chup = close > close[1]
if chup             
    if direction > 0                
        array.push(greenBars, 1)    
        array.push(redBars,   0)    
    else if direction < 0           
        array.push(greenBars, 0)    
        array.push(redBars,   1)    

    if direction != 0              
        array.shift(greenBars)      
        array.shift(redBars)       

    greenBarCount := array.sum(greenBars)
    redBarCount   := array.sum(redBars)

//BAR    
cond = greenBarCount >= 10

var int    ingreenbar  = 0
for i = 0 to 10
    if cond[i]
        if close > close [1]
            ingreenbar := ingreenbar + 1
        else
            ingreenbar := 0

updaygreen = ingreenbar >= 8
```

But it seems not working... Does anyone know how to do it? Please help me solve it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Green bars", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

barsBack = input.int(10)

var float[] green_bar_array = array.new_float()

if close > close[1]
    array.push(green_bar_array, close)

if array.size(green_bar_array) > barsBack
    array.shift(green_bar_array)

bool updaygreen = false
int green_count = 0

if array.size(green_bar_array) == barsBack
    for i = 1 to barsBack - 1
        if array.get(green_bar_array, i) >= array.get(green_bar_array, i - 1)
            green_count += 1
    if green_count >= 8
        updaygreen := true


if green_count > 0
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = high, style = label.style_label_down, size = size.tiny, text = str.tostring(green_count))

bgcolor(updaygreen ? color.lime : #00000000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. I've been trying for 10 hours and didn't success...one more further questions, what's the different between your solution and things like "sum(var, length)" in my case ? I was searching on tradingview before and found some script similar to my case but never work out...Your code are perfect and amazing without a doubt, I just want to learn something from professional people. Thanks again sir.

Comment: In theory it could be done that way with `sum` but it would be more complicated. The way your question was asked, it inferred that there would be an indeterminate number of red bars in between the green bars. That makes it difficult to use `sum` that requires you to have a fixed length. The way it's coded above, you could have many small red candles where price doesn't move much and you could still examine whether the green bars are continuing higher without having to know how many bars in total you need to go back over in order to find ten green bars.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation sir. Thank you.